# back up ubuntu system

Tags: backup

I have an external hard drive and I want to use free file sync to back up my data on this external hard drive. I know how to use free file syn, but I want to know how can I format my external hard drive. I am using ubuntu 10.04 version and need to back up the contents of my Desktop and Documents folder.

Hope to hear from you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted.

Choose **gpt** and **ext4** if you use Linux only (or if you are ok with installing **ext4** support on other OSes). Otherwise **gpt** + **ntfs** or **msdos** + **ntfs** (if winxp compatibility needed).